# How to sum all of the elements from int array with only one line of Scanner input

Tags: java, recursion, java.util.scanner, numberformatexception

I want to find the sum of array of integers using recursion and taking input with only one line like 1 2 3 4 5.What methods can i use to collect the data from the scanner because now i have only number format exception.

I tried to run it with initialized array and with all elements inputed on a new and it works but doesnt when i go for one line input like 1 2 3 4 5 like i have already mentioned

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArraySum {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        int[] arr = new int[5];
        int index = 0;

        int sum = arraySum(arr, index);
        System.out.println(sum);
    }

    static int arraySum(int[] arr, int index) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        String input = sc.next();
        arr[index] = Integer.parseInt(input.trim());

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(input);

        if(scanner.hasNext()) {
            if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
                int currentSum = arr[index] + arraySum(arr, index + 1);
                return currentSum;
            }
        }
      return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: First fill the array, then find the sum. I don't believe trying to do both at once is a great idea. Now, if you don't need the array except to find the sum; do you **really** need it? And do you really need the recursion? `Scanner scanner = new Scanner(sc.nextLine().trim());
  int total = 0;
  while (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
   total += scanner.nextInt();
  }
  return total;`

Comment: I know that is not good practice at all i Just do it for training and understanding

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this, where you read a line of input first, then pass it to a `Scanner` and sum up the various int values. This will loop forever – it's just an example to show you how it could work.

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
while (true) {
    int total = 0;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(reader.readLine());
    while (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
        total += scanner.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println("total: " + total);
}
```

Or you could use `String.split()`:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String line = reader.readLine();
String[] parts = line.split("\\s+"); // split on one or more whitespace characters
int total = 0;
for (String part : parts) {
    total += Integer.parseInt(part);
}
System.out.println("total: " + total);
```

Or you could use a `StringTokenizer`:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String line = reader.readLine();
StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
int total = 0;
while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
    total += Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken());
}
System.out.println("total: " + total);
```

Comment: I think i found other solution. Will  .Split(). ToArray() methods work... While scanning integer values to parse them split them with a space and put the into array

Comment: I updated my answer above to include an example using `String.split()` as well as `StringTokenizer`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using recursion.

It first will read the input line and split it into tokens. `nextLine()` will grab the the whole line as a string, and `split(" ")` will split it into an array of tokens on each `" "`.

Then it will recursively calculate the sum of the values as integers in that array. The recursive step uses an `offset` value to know where it is in the array. It will add the current value, starting at `arr[0]`, to the remainder of the recursion with the `offset` iterating in the recursive call.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArraySum {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] inputTokenArray = getInputArray();
        Integer sum = recursiveArraySum(inputTokenArray, 0);
        System.out.println(sum.toString());
    }

    public static String[] getInputArray() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = sc.nextLine();
        return input.split(" ");
    }

    public static Integer recursiveArraySum(String[] arr, Integer offset) {
        if (offset + 1 > arr.length) {
            return 0;
        }
        return Integer.parseInt(arr[offset]) + arraySum(arr, offset + 1);
    }

}
```

Can also be simplified, for example:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArraySum {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] inputTokenArray = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine().split(" ");
        Integer sum = arraySum(inputTokenArray, 0);
        System.out.println(sum.toString());
    }

    public static Integer arraySum(String[] arr, Integer offset) {
        return (offset + 1 > arr.length) ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(arr[offset]) + arraySum(arr, offset + 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `BufferReader` and a `Scanner` to read each int in the line and sum them up at the same time.

```
System.out.print("Enter numbers: ");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
Scanner in = new Scanner(reader.readLine());
int sum = 0;
while(in.hasNext()) {
    sum += in.nextInt();
}
System.out.println("Sum = " + sum);
```

Console:

```
Enter numbers: 1 2 3 4 5
Sum = 15
```